# How to Copy files from the remote machine using batch script

Tags: batch-file

i need help to compare these twofile and find any fail(word),

Could any one suggest me as I am a starter in batch Script ?, below is i have

```
ROBOCOPY C:\Windows\shape.txt \\foo\c:\TextFile Shape.txt /R:1 /W:0
```

The above command gives access denied

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you have problems with? please share your efforts! And clarify what you mean by "common word"; is that a constant value or does it need to be determined depending on the text data?

Comment: common word means i am look for any "fail", if i found then i need to check with another two txt log file for the word "fail" if found   i need to print that in separate in txt file

Comment: Please post your attempts by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38782086/edit) your question! this information is part of the question, and code is hardly readable in comments...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, your `file_name` files are located in a shared folder named `Shared` on each server, and you have access rights to each server. Replace file and server names in the script with real names and paths, and try the script from Admin Cmd Prompt. Post errors if any:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

:: Define variables
md "%temp%\test" & set "targetdir=%temp%\test"
set "path1=\\server1_name\Shared" & set "file1=log1.txt"
set "path2=\\server2_name\Shared" & set "file2=log2.txt"
set "path3=\\server3_name\Shared" & set "file3=log3.txt"

:: Temp map on your PC and loop through network drives to copy files
for /l %%i in (1,1,3) do (
    pushd !path%%i!
    copy "!file%%i!" "%targetdir%"

    :: Search for keyword in each file and copy related info to a new file
    find /i "fail" "%targetdir%\!file%%i!" >> %targetdir%\result.txt

    :: Unmap network drives
    popd )
echo/ & echo All tasks completed.
timeout 5
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks you for the script, i will test and let you know and i have a Query  what if the txt file we can access in browser as well, because i am using webserver so i can easily access the txt file in browser, so could you please tell me how to copy that as well

Comment: Error (1 was unexpected at this time for the above script

Comment: To copy a text open in a browser window, choose `File - Save Page As` in the browser Menu (press Alt to see it), or press Ctrl+S .

Comment: Updated the script with comments. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are exposed by a webserver, you can download them using the [Invoke-WebRequest](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217035) cmdlet. If its just a file share on a server, you can copy them using the [Copy-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113292) cmdlet.

If you want to find specific words in that file you can either use the [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet or you read the content using [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) and iterate over the lines / use a regex.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, is there any way in windows batch script instead of powershell

Comment: Yes there is but Im not that familiar with batch. However, you should had explicit ask for batch if you don't accept a PowerShell answer....

Comment: you can also write a powershell script and run that from the batch shell using teh command: `powershell.exe -file YourScript.ps1`

Comment: As of now i dont have access to test it powershell, i need to do it in Batch script as per the assignment , i can go with powershell once i found there is no other way. Please help me with batch script